# stickiness setting for websocket applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer, wss

Websocket connections are designed to be long-lasting and persistent. To ensure this, I configured the **stickiness** setting of my AWS ALB (application load balancer) to last for **one day**. Initially, this setup worked smoothly with three backend nodes (EC2 instances).

However, when I released a new update, I needed to replace these nodes one by one. When I replaced the first node, I noticed that all the traffic was redirected to the other two nodes, and when the new node came online, it did not receive any traffic. As a result, I was unable to run tests or view logs from the new node.

What's the best practices if you deal with this situation?